# unnesting namespace c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I have a nested namepace `DO` as a part of a big project.

```
namespace IDAL
{
    namespace DO
    {
        public struct MyStruct
        {
            // Code
        }
    }
}
```

I need to change the name of the `IDAL` namespace to `DalApi` and the nested namespace `IDAL.DO` to`DO`.

The first part was easy enough using the Visual Studio *Rename* option.

I ran into more difficulty with the second part. I can't use the *Rename* option to extract the namespace and make it a non nested namespace.

I tried just removing the outer namespace like this,

```
    namespace DO
    {
        public struct MyStruct
        {
            // Code
        }
    }
```

but the I needed to start fixing up all of the times that the namespace was referenced (i.e. `IDAL.DO.WeightCategory` - where WeightCategory is an enum needs to be changed to `DO.WeightCategory` just to give one example). While that seemed that it would work, it seemed that it was a lot of difficult work which probably had an easier solution.

I tried to use the `Ctrl+H` search and replace feature to try and replace all instances where this happened but it didn't seem to solve the problem (it was set to replace for entire solution).

Is there a Visual Studio 2019 tool where I can easily change (refactor) a nested namespace to a non nested namespace?

Comment: That's what tools like Resharper are for...

Comment: @PMF Why would you suggest Resharper for this if it's something that Visual Studio supports out of the box and the OP is already using? Resharper is so stupidly slow I never understand why people suggest it for simple stuff like this

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Since I've been used to it for so long, I sometimes don't recognize any more whether a features comes from Resharper or VS itself. Many features also were originally only available in RS, but became part of VS later. (Additionally, performance problems seem to be mostly gone with VS2022.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Visual Studio, while having the cursor on `MyStruct`, do a `CTRL`+`.` on it:

[image]

And then just click on "Move to namespace..." and write whichever namespace you want, and VS will take care of the rest:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you also need the effective namespace `IDAL.DO` to change? If not you could simply swap to the fully qualified namespace like so:

```cs
namespace IDAL.DO
{
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

If you do want to change the full namespace to become simply `DO` then refactoring tools are indeed what you'll need to use. The following links should get you started in that regard:

https://dev.to/gopkumr/adjust-namespaces-automatically-visual-studio-2019-1f0b
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/refactoring-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-method?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/move-type-to-matching-file?view=vs-2022